# refresh carousel bootstrap object

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

How do you refresh a bootstrap carousel object?

I'm trying to dynamically change the css properties of the caption object within the carousel, and its completely unresponsive. I'm guessing it's because the carousel object needs to be refreshed. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Could you show us what you have so far in terms of markup/JS?